# "kernel panic not syncing out of memory and no killable process"

Tags: installation, server, memory

I'm installing Ubuntu Server 10.04 on a Pentium 3 with 256 MB RAM,
I select install, continue with the process and when I see the "configuring apt sources" progress bar then I got the error:
"kernel panic not syncing out of memory and no killable process"
Does anyone know this problem??, do you think it could be because the size of the RAM??

Ive seen in the [Ubuntu Server Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/preparing-to-install.html) that I only need 128 MB RAM to install it. So I dont think its the problem.

Regards.

---

Edit:
I' ve made a new try downloading a minimal CD image and installing it, the packages needed were downloaded from internet and I haven't any problems.
This is the link to the [iso](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).

Answer (score 5):

Did you check the memory with the memtest86+ option when the CD boots?  Preferably keep it running overnight.  Just in case there is something wrong with it...

One possible reason for "out of memory" errors on systems with not much RAM can happen when `fsck` has to check a very large filesystem (it also depends on what filesystem, I guess, but don't know which ones are more likely to have this issue).

Something you can try is to create a swap partition and enable it (using [`swapon`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man8/swapon.8.html)) before starting the installation.

Comment: I agree to this, I have done installations on less however local caching or etc might be causing the memory errors.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that solution

Answer (score 1):

Try booting the Ubuntu Server installer with the parameter: lowmem=1